# MVC view model decoupling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model-binding, separation-of-concerns, loose-coupling

I am at the very first step of MVC.

In my first example I have a Model like so:

```
public class GuestResponse
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email")]
    [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify whether you'll attend")]
    public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
}
```

the Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["greeting"] = (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12 ? "Good morning" : "Good afternoon");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.View("Thanks", guestResp);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.View();
        }
    }
}
```

and a View:

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1>
        Thank you,
        <%: Model.Name  %>.</h1>
    <p>
        <% if (Model.WillAttend == true)
           {  %>
        It's great that you're coming. The drinks are already in
        the fridge!
        <% }
           else
           {  %>
        Sorry to hear you can't make it, but thanks for letting
        us know.
        <% } %>
    </p>
</div>
```

What seems strange to me, is that the View is thightly coupled with the Model: it uses code like `Model.WillAttend` ecc... So what happen if in a future time the Model changes? I should have to change all the snippets inside this particular View (but possibly also in many other views...) 
Is this tight-coupling or am I missing the point here?

**EDIT**

In the book the Author points out that this useful mechanism is

> Model Binding

*Given that the method [public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResp)] is being
invoked via an HTTP request, and that GuestResponse is a .NET type that is totally unknown to HTTP,
how can an HTTP request possibly supply a GuestResponse instance? The answer is model binding, an
extremely useful feature of ASP.NET MVC whereby incoming data is automatically parsed and used to
populate action method parameters by matching incoming key/value pairs with the names of properties
on the desired .NET type.
This powerful, customizable mechanism eliminates much of the humdrum plumbing associated
with handling HTTP requests, letting you work primarily in terms of strongly typed .NET objects rather
than low-level fiddling with Request.Form[] and Request.QueryString[] dictionaries, as is often
necessary in Web Forms. Because the input controls defined in RsvpForm.aspx render with names
corresponding to the names of properties on GuestResponse, the framework will supply to your action
method a GuestResponse instance already fully populated with whatever data the user entered into the
form.*

My two cents: but so, this mechanism give you the advantage of strongly typed classes inside the View (which, however, is really useful thanks to Visual Studio **Intellisense** feature, otherwise in my opinion also the Request.Form[] syntax would fit the same). On the other hand, you are tightly coupling the View with the Model, so that every tiny change to the Model will result in a cascade of changes on linked Views.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this tight coupling or am I missing the point here

Yes it is tight coupling and the point you maybe missing is - this isn't the `M` in MVC, this is a different type of model called a *view* model and it's supposed to be tailored for a specific view so it makes sense that it's coupled.

It's generally known as [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), a derivation of MVC which introduces the notion of view models to de-couple your actual model from the view.

Comment: I see your point... However this example is taken from the Book of Steven Sanderson on MVC. It is the very first example of MVC presented in the book, and the author explicity points out that this is MVC (not MVVM).

Comment: Well I guess he is right in some respects - however, the architecture is pretty much the same.